# How to switch md-switch for boolean string

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have data set which is having a value boolean string.As far I know we can't switch the md-switch with string values.How can make my md-switch with toggleable with this boolean strings?

my object having values as folows.

```
{
  code:'1',
  name: 'Name',
  active : 'true'
}
```

In my ng-repeat, I use this md-switch.

```
 <md-switch ng-model="group.active"  ng-change='vm.toggleActivesServiceGroup(group)'>
</md-switch>
```

How switch this for values on active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this to toogle the md-switch with `ng-true-value="'true'"`.

```
<md-switch ng-model="group.active" ng-true-value="'true'" ng-change='vm.toggleActivesServiceGroup(group)'>
</md-switch>
```

Hope this will help for some of having this problem.